# How to Enable HTML::TableExtract to Recognize Special Characters

Tags: html, perl, parsing, html-table

I was trying to parse a page that contain scientific notation (Greek, etc). 
This is the [page](http://www.violinet.org/vaxjo/vaxjo_detail.php?c_vaxjo_id=55). Note that there are other pages with more notations to be parsed.

For example it contain the following HTML

```
<td> human Interleukin 1&beta;        </td>
```

where `&beta` encode the Greek alphabet.

However after parsing with [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.11/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm) it became:

```
human Interleukin 1\x{3b2}
```

Is there a way to make the code below capture the original HTML as it is, 
i.e. maintaning `1&beta`.

```
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Data::Dumper;

# Local file for http://www.violinet.org/vaxjo/vaxjo_detail.php?c_vaxjo_id=55
my $file = "vaxjo_detail.php\?c_vaxjo_id\=50.html";

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new();
$te->parse_file($file);
my ($table) = $te->tables;
print Dumper $table ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did not return

```
human Interleukin 1\x{3b2}
```

It returned

```
human Interleukin 1β
```

Dumper simply prints that out as Perl string literal

```perl
"human Interleukin 1\x{3b2}"
```

Anyway, if you want the raw HTML instead of the text it represents, I believe passing `keep_html => 1` to the constructor will do the trick.